# Postgres slow WHERE id is ANY query on 100M row table

Tags: postgresql

I have a large table 'scores' containing over 100million rows in the following format:

```
(critic_id, book_id, score)
```

I have a primary key constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT pk_scoresid PRIMARY KEY (critic_id, book_id)
```

There are about 225.000 books, and about 500 critics.

Doing a query such as:

```
SELECT *
FROM scores s
WHERE s.critic_id = ANY(array[1,2,3,4,5])
```

The above query returns about 1.2 million rows. This takes about 35 seconds on my local machine. I would really like it to be <1 seconds if possible, since I want to do some post-calculations and send it back to my front-end. Is there any way to speed up the query?

Executing the query below takes about 5.5s for each of the critic id's seperately (which is still too long for my application):

```
SELECT * FROM scores s WHERE s.critic_id = 1          /* or 2, 3, 4.. */
```

**EDIT1**:

Output of:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM scores s WHERE s.critic_id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

"Bitmap Heap Scan on scores s  (cost=33998.40..658736.47 rows=1180328 width=16)"
"  Recheck Cond: (critic_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5}'::integer[]))"
"  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on pk_scoresid  (cost=0.00..33703.32 rows=1180328 width=0)"
"        Index Cond: (critic_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5}'::integer[]))"
```

**EDIT2**:

Tried the following, but that didn't improve performance much:

```
CREATE INDEX score_index
  ON score
  USING btree
  (critic_id);
ALTER TABLE score CLUSTER ON score_index;
```

.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM scores s WHERE s.critic_id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

"Bitmap Heap Scan on score s  (cost=22183.58..646085.28 rows=1188223 width=16)"
"  Recheck Cond: (detector_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5}'::integer[]))"
"  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on scores_index  (cost=0.00..21886.53 rows=1188223 width=0)"
"        Index Cond: (detector_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5}'::integer[]))"
```

**EDIT3**:

```
EXPLAIN (analyze, verbose) SELECT * FROM scores WHERE s.critic_id = 1 OR s.critic_id = 2 OR s.critic_id = 3 OR s.critic_id = 4 OR s.critic_id = 5

"Bitmap Heap Scan on public.scores s  (cost=23433.49..654761.58 rows=1183187 width=16) (actual time=145.373..7078.141 rows=1121375 loops=1)"
"  Output: critic_id, book_id, score"
"  Recheck Cond: ((s.critic_id = 1) OR (s.critic_id = 2) OR (s.critic_id = 3) OR (s.critic_id = 4) OR (s.critic_id = 5))"
"  Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 33440779"
"  Heap Blocks: exact=43398 lossy=185726"
"  ->  BitmapOr  (cost=23433.49..23433.49 rows=1188223 width=0) (actual time=137.729..137.729 rows=0 loops=1)"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on scores_index  (cost=0.00..4115.16 rows=222746 width=0) (actual time=60.175..60.175 rows=224275 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (s.critic_id = 1)"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on scores_index  (cost=0.00..4115.16 rows=222746 width=0) (actual time=18.473..18.473 rows=224275 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (s.critic_id = 2)"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on scores_index  (cost=0.00..4115.16 rows=222746 width=0) (actual time=21.429..21.429 rows=224275 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (s.critic_id = 3)"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on scores_index  (cost=0.00..4115.16 rows=222746 width=0) (actual time=18.918..18.918 rows=224275 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (s.critic_id = 4)"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on scores_index  (cost=0.00..5493.86 rows=297239 width=0) (actual time=18.729..18.729 rows=224275 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (s.critic_id = 5)"
```

Comment: What kind of index(es) on critic_id are you using?

Comment: It would be more conventional to use: `s.critic_id in (1,2,3,4,5)`

Comment: Try something like this: http://hastebin.com/raw/yosizepilu

Comment: Please update your post to include the list of indexes you have defined for the table and the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM scores s WHERE s.critic_id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);`

Comment: I updated the post with more info on my PK constraint, and output of EXPLAIN SELECT... Other suggestions didn't improve speed much.

Comment: Have you tried to create an index specifically for critic_id, e.g., something like: `CREATE INDEX scores_criticid_idx ON scores (critic_id);` ?

Comment: How long does it take to run the simplest variant of the query: `SELECT * FROM scores s WHERE s.critic_id = 1` ? (measure the time for each of the 5 IDs separately).

Comment: I added an index on critic_id, but it actually looks like it made it worse.. SELECT * FROM scores s WHERE s.critic_id = 1,2,.. takes about 5.5s for every query respectively

Comment: The output of `explain (analyze, verbose)` would be more helpful

Comment: @DavidAldridge `= ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3,4])` is what PostgreSQL turns `IN (1, 2, 3, 4) into internally, and unlike the `IN`-list form it can be supplied as a bind parameter. So I think it's useful to express it that way.

Comment: A scan of a 100-million-row table for multiple conditions isn't necessarily likely to be fast. Do you need the whole row? Can you `SELECT` just a couple of columns you require? What happens if you express it (for testing) as the `union` of four simple `select`s instead? Or an `OR` list, like `critic_id = 1 OR critic_id = 2 ...` etc? show `explain analyze`.

Comment: Updated with output of `EXPLAIN (analyze, verbose) SELECT * FROM scores s WHERE s.critic_id = 1 OR s.critic_id = 2 OR s.critic_id = 3 OR s.critic_id = 4 OR s.critic_id = 5`

Comment: @appel, well, if the simplest form of the query (`SELECT * FROM scores s WHERE s.critic_id = 1`) takes 5 seconds, then more complicated variants would be only longer. Do you really need all these 1.2 million rows as a result?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov In the 'book' table i have a column 'series_id' (every series has about 15 books). What I want in the end is the top 10 rated series, given an array of critic id's (ie. to answer the question "What series do these critics think are the best"). To do this I want to sum the scores for each book in the series for the given critic_ids, and then average the scores for every critic.

Comment: You should probably be trying to optimise the query that will give you the final result that you want, not this one.

Comment: What kind of host is running this database (OS, CPU, Memory etc.)? How is the cluster configured (cache and memory related parameters)?

Answer (score 0):

If this is the usual predicate that you apply to queries on the table, in which you select a fairly small subset of critic ids, then with the critic_id indexed you can cluster the table on that index to physically resort it.

This will co-locate all rows having the same value of critic_id, and improve both the likelihood of that index being used and the performance when it is.

It would might harm performance on queries that select by book_id if there is already some inherent clustering by book_id in the table.

Comment: I did the following, but that didn't improve speed much. Am I doing it correctly? `CREATE INDEX score_index
  ON score
  USING btree
  (critic_id);
ALTER TABLE score CLUSTER ON score_index;`

Answer (score 0):

May be you should perform data denormalization:

```
CREATE TYPE book_score AS (
   book_id int,
   score int
);

create table score(
   critic_id int primary key,
   scores book_score[]
);
```

Of course it creates problem with inserting and updating, but it reduces table size radically.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM scores s
WHERE s.critic_id = 1
   UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM scores s
WHERE s.critic_id = 2
   UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM scores s
WHERE s.critic_id = 3
   UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM scores s
WHERE s.critic_id = 4
   UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM scores s
WHERE s.critic_id = 5
```

and (eventually) add an index only on critic_id.